# Bosonic representation of delta function for Grassmann-even quantity

Tags: supersymmetry, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Suppose I have 2 Grassmann scalars $\theta$ and $\bar{\theta}$ and form the bosonic quantity $X = \bar{\theta}\theta$. Is there a purely bosonic representation of the delta function $\delta(X - \overline{\theta}\theta)$, which can be used in integrals to replace
$$f(\bar{\theta}\theta) = \int dX \;\delta(X - \bar\theta\theta) f(X).$$

(By purely bosonic I mean that we do not introduce two new Grassmann scalars and write $X = \bar{\eta}\eta$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{1|0}} \! dX ~\delta(X - \bar\theta\theta) f(X) 
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{1|0}} \! dX ~\delta(X) f(X+ \bar\theta\theta)\cr ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dX_B ~\delta(X_B) f(X_B+ \bar\theta\theta)\cr 
~=~&f(\bar{\theta}\theta). \end{align}$$

1. In the 1st equality, we used that an integral measure is translation invariant.
2. In the 2nd equality, we used that an integral over a Grassmann-even real [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/supernumber) $X\in\mathbb{R}^{1|0}$ is by definition given by the corresponding integral over its body $X_B\in\mathbb{R}$, cf. Ref. 1.
3. In the 3rd equality, we used the defining property of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

References:

1. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992; p.7.